# Using a function for message in smtplib email

Tags: python, function, email, smtplib

I am trying to send an email to myself with the results of some webscraping I did. The scraping all takes place in a function. So I tried to set the function as the message for my email but it's just not working.

Here is my code (still fairly new so please don't bash the code too much, I know I can refactor it a lot still)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import requests
import smtplib

page = requests.get("https://www.sportsinteraction.com/soccer/england/premier-league-betting/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
matches = soup.find_all(class_="game")

def betting_odds(data):
    for games in data:
        teams = games.find_all(class_="name")
        odds = games.find_all(class_="price wide")
        if len(games.find_all(class_="date")) > 0:
            print(games.find(class_="date").get_text())
        team1 = teams[0].get_text()
        draw = teams[1].get_text()
        team2 = teams[2].get_text()
        odds1 = odds[0].get_text()
        odds_draw = odds[1].get_text()
        odds2 = odds[2].get_text()
        print("{}  {} \n{}  {} \n{}  {} \n".format(team1, odds1, draw, odds_draw, team2, odds2))    

fromx = 'email@email.com'
to = 'email@emai.com'
msg = MIMEText('Here are the odds for the upcoming premier league games\n\n{}'.format(betting_odds(matches)))
msg['Subject'] = 'Premier League Odds'
msg['From'] = fromx
msg['To'] = to

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()

smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login('Email@email.com', 'password')
smtpObj.sendmail(fromx, to, msg.as_string()) 
smtpObj.quit()
```

When I run this, the results all show up in the Shell exactly how I want them to appear and then the email sends. Once I get the email it has the subject and the first line of the message is correct, but then it says None.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your function does not return anything, it just prints.

Comment: when I changed the print statements to return, the email message just returned the first line and nothing after. any Idea why this would occur?

Comment: Because your first iteration will return already, unlike a `print()` which can be run multiple times.

Comment: Because you aren't returning all the lines, just the first one. I would suggest adding a variable `message = ""` before `for games in data:` and then instead of the print add each value to the variable `message +=  ("{}  {} \n{}  ...)`

Comment: I also tried creating a variable and adding each value, but that didn't seem to work either, I will test that again.

Comment: It worked!!! I must have messed something up when I created the variable to hold the string the first time. thanks to both of you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. I completed it by creating a variable to hold the strings and continued to concatenate them together through the loops. Then I returned the variable at the end.

Cheers!